# How do I show only one column of my data in my ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a database with information, when I request the data I only want one column to show in my `ListView`, so that the user can select the information they want to display

This is my database helper:

```java
public Cursor viewData () {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from " +TABLE_NAME, null);

        return res;

    }
```

And my code:

```java
private void viewData() {
        Cursor cursor = db.viewData();

        if (cursor.getCount()== 0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"No Data To Show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                listItems.add(cursor.getString(0));//index 1 is name, 0 is ID
            }
            String[] StringArray = new String[]{
                    DatabaseHelper.COL_2
            };
            int[] IntArray = new int[]{
                    R.id.textView1
            };

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, StringArray, IntArray);
            userList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }
```

my item_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mway">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Doesn't your code work?

Comment: the code works but it displays the column information a page apart...

Comment: Post the item_layout xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout's height to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

so it will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mway">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you... but that didn't work... the column i want displayed is "name"... it displays but at the top of the background picture...

Comment: ok, I found the problem.... the android:background="@drawable/mway"... i deleted it and now the names are displayed under each other...

Comment: Do you see all the items now in 1 page?

Comment: yes thanks... the "item_layout.xml" file is displayed over the activity, and when I added the background... it forces the data on the length of each entry...

Comment: Check `mway` in the `drawable` folder. Maybe it needs to be adjusted too. Anyway keep this atribute: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`